# Relational Algebra union, join and intersect

Tags: database, relational, algebra

I'm studying computer science and am brushing up on database systems. I'm having difficulties grasping certain parts.

Say I have the following relations:

```
Lecturers(LecturerID, Name, DeptID)
Course(DeptID, CrsCode, CrsName, Description)
```

I note that they both share a common attribute, DeptID, therefore they are union-compatible.

How would I go about listing all courses that are taught by lecturers belonging to computer science dept (CS) or electronic engineering dept (eEng)?

My answer would be using intersection with selection. Would the following be correct or near the mark?

```
πDeptID,CrsName(Course) intersection πDeptID,Name(σDeptID = CS or DeptID = eEng(Lecturers))
```

I'm sure join could be used here, but I'm unsure how to use the predicate with it.

Thanks for your help. Once I understand what to use in a few situations I'm sure the rest will be easier.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what does this have to do with relational algebra?

Comment: IIRC back then, over 7 years ago, the task of that particular class was to express the solution to the question in relational algebra, not SQL.

Comment: But you accepted an answer that has nothing to do with relational algebra. It's just SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a simple [INNER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join) for this.

```
SELECT DEPTID, CRSNAME
FROM COURSE A
INNER JOIN LECTURERS B on A.DEPTID=B.DEPTID
WHERE B.DEPTID='eENG' or B.DEPTID='CS'
```

Comment: Sure, expressions can be used to carry out actions of other expressions. Thanks for the SQL, but I don't know how to express that in relational algebra.

Comment: I'll flag this as the answer. I didn't know there were so many different names for the same function. Inner join is what I'm taught as natural join. I just needed to work out how to express this using rel. algebra and I think I've cracked it as:

`σLecturers.DeptID = CS or Lecturers.DeptID = eEng(πDeptID, CrsName(Course)) x (πDeptID, Name(Lecturers))`

Answer (score 0):

There must be also a table for Departments, as you have a refference to the DeptID field, which should be an INT. I assume it is DEPARTMENTS with DeptID and Code as fields. In this case:

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
  Course C
INNER JOIN 
  LECTURERS L on C.DeptId = L.DeptID
INNER JOIN 
  Departments D on C.DeptID = D.DeptID
WHERE 
  D.code = 'eENG' or D.code = 'CS'
```

Comment: The DeptID field is just a key for each of the two relations, as far as I'm aware? This example is taken from a practice exam paper and there's no mention of another relation. Would you be able to express your SQL in terms of algebra? While I'm tested on expressing this particular question as SQL I'm also expected to express it algebraically.